# Shell script to check if process is running everyday

Tags: shell

Can someone please let me know how to complete the scenario below:

I have 3 processes (TC_ME, PS_ME, and NM_ME) running on a machine. When these services go down, they do not send out any alert or mail.

I would like to write a shell script based out of these processes, so whenever the processes go down, I would require an alert.

Will create an autosys job based on this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
#! /bin/bash
while :
do
    RESULT=`ps -ef | grep "TC_ME\|PS_ME\|NM_ME" | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v $0 | wc -l`
    if [ "$RESULT" != "3" ]; then
            echo `date` ":   some of your processes not running"
    else
            echo `date` ":   processes runs"
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```

Eg;

```
user@host:/tmp$ ./processesCheck.sh
Wed Oct 5 15:54:01 EEST 2016 :   some of your processes not running
Wed Oct 5 15:54:11 EEST 2016 :   some of your processes not running
Wed Oct 5 15:54:21 EEST 2016 :   some of your processes not running
Wed Oct 5 15:54:31 EEST 2016 :   some of your processes not running
```

you can also redirect to a log file as below;

```
user@host:/tmp$ nohup ./processesCheck.sh >> processes.log
```

Answer (score 0):

if i were to do with the command below, where Ownerserver is a common word for all the above processes can i edit the script as below?

while :
do

RESULT=`ps -ef | grep "OwnerServer" | grep -v 'grep' | wc -l`
    if [ "$RESULT" -gt 1 ]; then
               echo `date` ":   processes runs"
    else
              echo `date` ":   some of your processes not running"
    fi
    sleep 10
done